# What's the best WYSIWYG editor when using the ASP.NET MVC Framework?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, xhtml, wysiwyg

Was wondering what the best WYSIWYG editor that I can embed in a web-site based on the ASP.NET MVC Framework? Ideally it should be Xhtml compliant and allow users to embed images etc.

The only one I've used before is the [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/), how well does this work with the MVC - has anyone tried...?

My main requirements are:

- Xhtml compliance
- Deprecate (as best it can) when Javascript is disabled
- Modify the toolbar options
- Skinable (at least easily change the look and feel)
- Easy to use client side api
- Plays nicely with the ASP.NET MVC framework

**Edit:**

As [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590960/whats-the-best-wysiwyg-editor-when-using-the-asp-net-mvc-framework/591025#591025) said, the [XStandard](http://www.xstandard.com/) editor is good, but requires a plug-in...what are your thoughts on requiring a plug-in for web-site functionality?

Thanks,
Kieron

**Additional info:**

As [Hippo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590960/whats-the-best-wysiwyg-editor-when-using-the-asp-net-mvc-framework/591037#591037) answered, the TinyMCE edit is ideal - for completness here's there download page:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download.php

There's a download for .NET, JSP, ColdFusion, PHP and a jQuery plug-in too.
Also, there are language packs available.

Been using it for a while now, best editor I've used. Thanks all!

Comment: Requiring a plug-in (that the user has to install) is bad.  If you have a captive audience (like on a corporate network), then maybe you could do it.  But otherwise, forget it.  That's what I reckon :)

Comment: Thanks for your additional info. Helped me make my decision.

Comment: This question has been here for years? Why close it now?

Comment: ...and more to the point, what's wrong with this question?

Comment: This question is very constructive and helpful for Asp.Net MVC developers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I really like [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) which also should fit your requirements. It is well documented and offers a lot of possibilities to configure.

Comment: Great suggestion, I'll probably be using this myself now.

Comment: There's a great jQuery plug-in for it on the TinyMCE site too. Well worth it (:

Comment: It's [LGPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License). I need something I can embed in my proprietary projects. Any good alternative?

Comment: Why is it a problem for you to embed an LGPL project into a commercial project? LGPL is not viral.

Comment: TinyMCE is a great WYSIWYG, but Telerik has a very nice one!    http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/editor/imagebrowser

Comment: @RadimBurget, LGPL requires you to disclose your source-code. [Am I wrong](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/)?

Comment: The LGPL is similar to the GPL, but is more designed for software libraries where you want to allow non-GPL applications to link to your library and utilise it. If you modify the software (LGPL), you still have to give back the source code, but you are allowed to link it with proprietary stuff without giving the source code to all of that back.

Comment: here is an example to use tinymce editor control in mvc with code and demo.. this is free javascript editor and one of the best..  hope it helps.. [text editor control is asp.net mvc](http://codeanalyze.com/Articles/Details/20182/Rich-text-editor-control-in-aspnet-mvc-using-javascript-free)

Answer (score 6):

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) (the next version of FCKEditor) is in beta, but looks like it might eventually be pretty nice.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a good link to using FckEditor with MVC Framework

[Using FCK Editor with ASP.NET MVC](http://msmvps.com/blogs/superska/archive/2009/04/06/using-fck-editor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at Aloha Editor http://aloha-editor.org which comes with a new concept: complete frontend editing with no iframe and real WYSIWYG.

Comment: I'll just note that this answer was provided by the team leader of Aloha Editor - http://aloha-editor.org/about.php, which **YOU** should have done, Haymo.

Comment: Note that this project has been discontinued

Answer (score 2):

Search on the JQuery homepage for a list of JQuery compatible WYSIWYG editors. There are quite a few there: [JQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/wysiwyg+type:project_project)

Answer (score 2):

I really like the simplicity and extensability of [markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)

It's actually not a WYSIWYG, but we just changed from using TinyMCE to markItUp quite recently and I must say that it has been working very well!

And best of all, it's **very** easy to extend.

Answer (score 0):

[XStandard](http://www.xstandard.com/) fits most of your requirements, but it does require your clients to install a browser plug-in.

Comment: Looks good, but a low friction (no plug-ins) editor would be better I know...what does the community think?

Comment: @smiller - depends entirely on the requirements for the app. A plug-in for a public forum is a dumb idea, but for a company intranet might be a good solution.

Comment: You don't want visitors to your site to have to install something.  Flash is bad enough but just for an editor?  No.

Comment: This is a valid solution in some cases so +10 to counter the haters.