# What is a good simple wysiwyg text editor to use with asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wysiwyg

What is a good and simple wysiwyg text editor to use with asp.net mvc I only need the bold and insert a link functionalities.

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best free online wysiwyg editor I could embed to my client's website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191188/what-is-the-best-free-online-wysiwyg-editor-i-could-embed-to-my-clients-website) and [What's the best WYSIWYG editor when using the ASP.NET MVC Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590960/whats-the-best-wysiwyg-editor-when-using-the-asp-net-mvc-framework)

Answer (score 3):

I use [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

It's really easy to use and looks fantastic.  You can customise it so only what you want is shown.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/editor.aspx) has one, and it's open source.

This is a very young production and it is very basic.

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik's Kendo UI Editor](http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/ui-widgets/editor/overview.aspx) - I find this very nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use the ASP.Net Ajax control toolkits HTML editor or third party tools.

Following is the link to HTML editor that you might be already knowing;

http:// www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx

http:// www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx

http://mvccontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

http://richtexteditor.com/mvc/