# asp.net mvc wysiwyg editor w/ database images upload/preview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, wysiwyg

Is there any jQuery WYSIWYG editor w/ ability to upload and then preview images to/from the database?
Maybe there are kinda adapters for well-known CKEditor + CKFinder to work with database?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" [What's the best WYSIWYG editor when using the ASP.NET MVC Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590960/whats-the-best-wysiwyg-editor-when-using-the-asp-net-mvc-framework) " has a few WYSIWYG suggestions. Personally, I like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/). They have an [image manager](http://www.tinymce.com/enterprise/mcimagemanager.php) that's pretty slick too.

- Easy to integrate. MCFileManager compatible.
- Create folders. Upload
  images.
- Crop & Resize (if GD is enabled).
- Thumbnail auto generation
  (if GD is enabled).
- EXIF jpg/jpeg and tiff thumbnail support. Highly
  customizable configuration.
- Works perfectly in fullscreen and
  "popup" mode. Full source included, not obfuscated.
- Ajax based
  interface using a JSON bridge. Multilanguage support.

As far as database image support goes, you can use an image list (see http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=12634 for similar discussion in php):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
  theme: "advanced",
  mode : "textareas",
  plugins : "style",
  theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "styleprops",
  content_css : "../tiny.css",
  external_image_list_url : "Image/List",
  browsers : "msie,gecko,opera"
});
</script>
```

Where `ImageController.List()` is a controller action that returns a JSON array of action links to your images retrieved from the database and `ImageController.View(id)` is an action that returns an image:

```
["test_before.jpg", "Image/View/bread"],
["cherry.jpg", "Image/View/cherry"],
["bread.jpg", "Image/View/bread"],
["test_after.jpg", "Image/View/cherry"]
```

Then to upload, you'll need to create another action that will accept a posted file (image) and save it to your database. There are a few open source plugins that will take care of this for you:

- http://tinymcefckfilemanger.codeplex.com/
- http://aspnetadvimage.codeplex.com/

Comment: But what about database connection?

Comment: There's a discussion about database images on their forum, but it's php specific. http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=12634

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried this solution and it works basically. I'm just wondering whether there are a database connector which gives you the same possibilities to work with files as using a file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using http://labs.corefive.com/projects/filemanager/ plugin. Supports CKEditor and FCKEditor.

Ofcourse you have to program the part where you want to store the files etc. But they do have a few examples included.